# Unwanted Prefix in SoapCore Response in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap

I am writing a `SoapCore` web service in `.NET Core 5.0` and I have successfully been able to execute the request via `SOAPUI` and get back a valid response. The only thing I don't like is that it puts unwanted prefixes in the repose message. For example, in this response:

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <s:Body>
        <getMeterIntervalDataByTimeSliceResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
          <getMeterIntervalDataByTimeSliceResult xmlns:d4p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MeterDataWebService.Models" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <d4p1:AccountId>1234567890</d4p1:AccountId>
            <d4p1:ID>0</d4p1:ID>
            <d4p1:IntervalEndTime>2020-12-22T15:30:57.3705724-05:00</d4p1:IntervalEndTime>
            <d4p1:IntervalLengthInSeconds>PT5M</d4p1:IntervalLengthInSeconds>
            <d4p1:Load>2345.8010350836185</d4p1:Load>
            <d4p1:MeterChannel>1</d4p1:MeterChannel>
            <d4p1:TimeZone>UT</d4p1:TimeZone>
            <d4p1:UnitOfMeasure>KM</d4p1:UnitOfMeasure>
            <d4p1:UtcOffset>0</d4p1:UtcOffset>
          </getMeterIntervalDataByTimeSliceResult>
        </getMeterIntervalDataByTimeSliceResponse>
      </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

How do I get rid of the "d4p1" prefix?

Comment: Are you using xml serialization in your service.  To remove the prefixes you need to add to the [XmlElement(ElementName = "AccountId", Namespace = "")] a namespace with an empty string.

Comment: @jdweng instead if i have to replace the d4p1 ? I need to set xmlns:a to my responseresult but i don't understand how do It. I would avoid to implement a message format class besause if i understand correctly, It will be an extra parsing work on a result already done.

Comment: @dpope : It is best to leave the namespace d4p1.  To parse all you need to do is to add an attribute to your c# classes defining the namespace.  It is easier to add the namespace than to modify the xml.

Comment: What work have you already done for parsing?

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. It was in my `Startup.cs` class.

```cs
app.UseSoapEndpoint<ISampleService>("/Service.asmx", new BasicHttpBindingg(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);
```

I had forgotten to add the `SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer` part.

Comment: For .NET 8 when using top-level route registration (instead of `UseEndpoints()`), you can pull this into its own static method that takes an `IApplicationBuilder` parameter to avoid an unfortunate ambiguous reference compiler error.